# Unable to import flask_login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am following the book explore flask on explore flask site, I am getting this error, I just installed flask-login and import this as following

pip install flask-login

from flask_login import login_required

I expect to save this normally without any errors, but VS CODE terminal show this error
"Unable to import 'flask_login'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the version of Flask-Login which is compatible with your Python Version. 
If you're using Python 3 in your Flask App you need pip3 to install compatible parts.

Try:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then:

```
pip3 install flask-login
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
I have to upgrade my pip as,
python -m pip install --upgrade pip,
after that I installed and no issue.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

- **First**, make sure that flask_login was installed successfully by running "pip list" in your project directory terminal, If it isn't there then you should install it again
- **Second**, if it is there so make sure of any typo mistakes, also you can share that piece of code to check it.

Comment: Thanks It is installed but not compatible with my pip version, Issue solved .